# Retrieving data from Postgres Sql and displaying in a datepicker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, ejs

I am a newbie in fullstack development. I am doing my first project using postgresql, nodejs and express(ejs template). In my task list project i have a duedate option, where i enter a duedate(date picker) for a task and it get saved in the postgres database. I have an edit option aswell with a datepicker. how can i retreive the date in the 'dd/mm/yyyy' format from the database and display it inthe date picker in the edit page?.is it possible. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Sure it is possible. What is the datatype of the column in the database?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add relevant code that you have tried. The Node.js `pg` package for Postgres has excellent docs for your reference.

Comment: i have tried Extract in Postgres, i have tried with the datatype date and timestamp. both gave me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What gets stored in the DB for date will probably look different then what you see on the front-end, simply because date / time is usually stored as UTC etc ( this will depend on how you have the table configured)

Next, you can use javascript built in date function like toLocaleDateString('en-US') to get a mm/dd/yyyy format from the stored date in the DB

What this means is that on the front-end you would pull the date from the DB as normal, then for the date-picker you would just pass the date over like

```
 let myDate = new date([date from db); // this create a new date object off the date from the DB 

 //Now we make is a readable date 
 // myDate = myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // will give mm/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: i have tried this <% let myDate = new Date(task.duedate) %> 
                <%  task.duedate = task.duedate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') %> i am getting an error .localestring is not defined. but i can see in the console i am getting the correct format. how can i put this to the datepicker?. Thank you very much

Comment: the data need to be converted to a 'date' object then you can use tolocaldatestring. In your code you have myDate but don't use it for the toLocalDateString.

Comment: first attempt - `<% let myDate = new Date(task.duedate) %>
<%= myDate = myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') %><input type="date" id="editTaskDueDate" value="<%= myDate %> " name="duedate" class="form-control datepicker">`, second attempt- `<input type="date" id="editTaskDueDate" value="<%= moment(task.duedate).format('DD-MM-YYYY') %>" name="duedate" class="form-control datepicker">` I am actually getting an output on the front end inthe date format, but wheni tried that on the value of the date picker this is not working